# QQ-Plot for data on skewed t distribution in R

Tags: r, skewness, t-distribution, qq-plot

I have been trying to plot my financial data against a skewed t distribution in a QQ plot in R for some time now, but I have only managed to do it against a symmetric t distribution so far.

I use the following code for the symmetric t-distribution:

1. Fit the data to a t distribution:

```r
t_mkt <- fit.st(factor_return["2007/2017-10-31"])
df_mkt <- t_mkt$par.ests["nu"]
```

2. Plot as a QQ Plot:

```r
chart.QQPlot(factor_return["2007/2017-10-31"], distribution="t", 
             distributionParameter="df=df_mkt" , 
             main="MKT-Factor t dist. Q-Q Plot")
```

I know that I can fit the data to a skewed t-distribution with this function:

```r
sstdFit(factor_returnMKT["2007/2017-10-31"])
```

But now I do not know how to plot it as a QQ Plot.

Answer (score 0):

The data format isn't clear from the question but it appears `factor_return` may be a list of vectors. A ggplot approach to creating a skewed t [Q-Q plot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_qq.html) would thus be something like

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(skewt)

skew = 1.1 # a mild right skew as an example
ggplot(tibble(return = factor_return["2007/2017-10-31"]), 
              aes(sample = return) +
  geom_qq_line(distribution = qskt, dparams = list(gamma = skew)) +
  geom_qq(distribution = qskt, dparams = list(gamma = skew)
```

where `skewt::qskt()` is one choice for a skewed t implementation which has `gamma` as its skew parameter. Various other skewed t implementations are available from other packages.

A second approach, using base R graphics rather than ggplot, is

```r
stats::qqnorm(distribution = function(x) { return(qskt(x, df = ..., gamma = ...)) })
```

A third possibility, albeit one fairly specific to this question's details, may be

```r
chart.QQPlot(distribution = "st", 
             distributionParameter = "location = ..., scale = ..., 
             shape = ...")
```

However, this capability [is not well documented](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PerformanceAnalytics/index.html) and may not be well supported.